# Jquery Popup - How to blur or remove alongside a toggle event

Tags: jquery, css

I have made a popup menu which toggles on click. I would like to keep this functionality but to also add the ability to click anywhere else within the page to remove the class.

Any help would be much appreciated. See code and demo below

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3NrZu/)

HTML

```
<div class="tree-wrapper">
    <div class="example-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-popup">Toggle</a>
    </div>
    <span id="popup">
        <ol>
            <li class="new-folder"><a href="#">New Folder</a></li>
            <li class="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rename</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cut</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
            <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
        </ol>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var popupToggle = $(".tree-wrapper .toggle-popup");

$(function () {

    popupToggle.click(function(e) {
        var popupToggleLink = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        popupToggleLink.toggleClass("open");
        popupToggleLink.closest(".tree-wrapper").find("#popup").toggleClass("open").css('left',e.pageX).css('top',e.pageY);
    });

});
```

CSS

```
#popup {
    display: none;
}
#popup.open {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    // Your code here
    if ($(e.target).closest('.tree-wrapper').length !== 0) return;
    $(".tree-wrapper").find("#popup").removeClass("open");
    popupToggle.removeClass("open");
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NrZu/2/)

Comment: Your example does work but it doesnt allow the removal of the class within the tree-wrapper div.

Comment: it doesnt remove the open class from the toggle either

Comment: @Parallel2ne: I have updated the code. Its now removing the class from both.

Comment: Thanks that does work but you still cannot click within the tree-wrapper to remove the popup. Is that possible?

Comment: See the click inside the `popup` is disabled for this because inside `popup` you have links and we don't want to hide the `popup` on click of the links, right? Best option could be using this: http://jsfiddle.net/3NrZu/4/

Answer (score 1):

The `event.stopPropagation()` can be used to prevent the event from bubbling to the `document` object once clicked on the link. Add an event handler on the `document` object to hide the popup.

Additionally I've added an event handler on the popup itself so you can still click the links within the popup. Same principle as the `popupToggle.click()`

```
var popup = $("#popup"),
    popupToggle = $(".tree-wrapper .toggle-popup");

$(function () {
    // toggle popup but don't bubble the event to the document
    popupToggle.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        popup.toggleClass("open").css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY});
    });

    // keep toggle open but don't bubble event to document
    popup.click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // close popup when clicked on document
    $(document).click(function(){
        popup.toggleClass("open", false);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/5fKEu/